# how to add payment_behavior to default_incomplete in Laravel cashier new subscription

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

In the stripe documentation, we have the option to pass 'payment_behavior' => 'default_incomplete', in order to create a subscription with the payment method.

In cashier we have a trial option but what if we don't want to use trail then how can the subscription get created without a payment method?

```
$subscription = $user->newSubscription('default', $validated['priceId'])
            ->trialDays(14)->create();
```

This is my code, I would like to remove the

> trailDays

option and add payment_behavior to default_incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `trialDays()` if you don't want a trial and then pass the desired additional Stripe parameters in third argument as noted in the Laravel Cashier docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/billing#additional-details

Answer (score 0):

Try `ignoreIncompletePayments` method without `trialDays`.

```
$subscription = $user->newSubscription('default', $validated['priceId'])->ignoreIncompletePayments()->create();
```

The status will be `default_incomplete` but if you invoke `subscribed` method it will result false.